# Insults in Chinese

Tags: mandarin, mainland-china, colloquialisms

*Please answer in simplified characters.*

I've studied Chinese for quite a few years but I still don't know how to insult anyone. I've got to bring it to them hard and fast, strong, relentless. I'm obviously not going to go around insulting anyone, I'd rather just know this for the novelty value.

The only insult I know is:

> 笨蛋!

Are there any others?

Comment: This list would be endless...

Comment: This is easy to Google, but I feel bad for finding such information for someone else... ><

Answer (score 2):

First  level: 笨蛋，傻瓜/Dumb-ass(Sha Gua)

Second level: 脑残/Brainless/Retard(Nao Can)，二B(Er B)，傻B/傻Ⅹ(Sha B/Sha Cha)

I am not going to translate the last few, they are basically comparing people to private parts......and please....don't say the words in second level to anyone...especially if they are not even your friend.

Answer (score 0):

This one for example is very common

xx個屁 / xx個頭xx-gèpì / xx-gètóuxx 
Meaning: my ass 
(interjection, as in 
A: 這電影好浪漫喔。 
B: 浪漫**個屁**阿!
A: This movie is so romantic. 
B: Romantic my ass!)

You'll find a whole bunch of them here. They have some notes on the really strong ones. As for the usage I'll leave it up to you. Have fun!

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_(Mandarin)/Slang